# format / rewrite old ide flash module

Tags: flash-memory

I have an old PC where the disk is a 32mb IDE flash module. 
BIOS boots the Flash, works good.
But if I am in a Linux distro (tinycore/arch/puppy) the flash module is not recognized nor mountable.

On the flash module there is a custom Windows MCE powered by Gio. I want to replace that with a Linux kernel but I failed trying to access that memory so far.

I already tried setting the jumper in every variation.
Could it be that the Manufacturer prevent access to it in BIOS?

Below is a picture of the flash ide module. Maybe someone has an idea how to format this?

[image: ide flash module]

Comment: What's the manufacturer and model name? Under Linux (preferably a live distribution with ample hardware support like [Knoppix](http://knoppix.net/) or [SystemRescueCD](http://www.sysresccd.org/) or [Ubuntu](http://ubuntu.com/)), what is the output of `lspci` and `cat /proc/partitions`?

Comment: Hi. Its Apacer, P/N: 81.78015.400 | T/N: TB840 |M/N: AP-FM03244B | 200432402936, written on 1 of the Chips: SST|55LD017B|40-C-TQW|0419216-A21

Comment: since bios "sees" the chip but in the OS its not visible i am clueless. how is that technicaly possible?

Comment: Apparently the BIOS has a driver for the chip. This may be a very basic driver, typically slow and read-only. Linux may not have a driver for it, or you may not have found how to access it. Again, what is the output of `lspci` and `cat /proc/partitions`?